# Placa de Video GeForce GT 520M

Tags: drivers, video, dell, vga

*Translated text (using Google Translate):*

Good afternoon,

I have a Dell XPS-14z laptop it has a GeForce GT 520M 1GB. I'm not getting this video card work properly because Microport output -> VGA image is not sent to the monitor. How do I solve this problem? How do I know if placated is working 100%?

Thank you!

*Original text:*

Boa tarde,

Tenho um notebook Dell XPS-14z ele tem uma placa de vídeo GeForce GT 520M 1Gb. Não estou conseguindo fazer essa placa de vídeo funcionar corretamente pois a saída microport -> VGA não está enviado imagem para o monitor. Como resolvo esse problema? Como que eu sei se aplaca está funcionando 100%?

Obrigado!

Comment: Please ask questions in english - if english is not your native tongue, please use a translation tool such as google-translate to help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

open Displays and mark mirror display checkbox and see what you get  (
Displays abertos e checkbox marca de visualização de espelho e ver o que você ganha)